# PInvoke I_NetLogonControl2

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I need to invoke I_NetLogonControl2 from c#. Here I how I am doing it

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, PreserveSig = true)]
public static extern uint LsaQueryInformationPolicy(SafeLsaPolicyHandle policyHandle, uint informationClass, out IntPtr buffer);  


[DllImport("NetApi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint I_NetLogonControl2(
    [In, Optional] string ServerName, 
    [In] DWORD FunctionCode,
    [In] DWORD QueryLevel,
    [In] byte[] InputData,
    out  IntPtr QueryInformation
    );

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct LSA_UNICODE_STRING : IDisposable
{
    public UInt16 Length;
    public UInt16 MaximumLength;
    public IntPtr Buffer;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct POLICY_PRIMARY_DOMAIN_INFO
{
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING Name;
    public IntPtr Sid;
}

status = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(LsaPolicyHandle,
         (uint) POLICY_INFORMATION_CLASS.PolicyPrimaryDomainInformation,
                              out ppPDI);

var val = (POLICY_PRIMARY_DOMAIN_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ppPDI, 
                                     typeof(POLICY_PRIMARY_DOMAIN_INFO));
Console.WriteLine("vALUE = {0}", Marshal.PtrToStringUni(val.Name.Buffer));

status = I_NetLogonControl2("", (uint)5 /* NETLOGON_CONTROL_REDISCOVER */, 2, val.Name.Buffer, out handle);
if (status != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I_NetLogonControl2 returned error value = {0}", status);
    return false;
}
```

When I invoke I_NetLogonControl2 I get an error saying that the stack I unbalanced since the parameters do not match the parameters in native code. I am not sure what I am really missing here. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

[UPDATE] After the changes and with the new code that is updated in the above code snippet, I am getting an AccessViolationException when I invoke the I_NetLogonControl2. Not sure what is going on. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Whenever you ask about an error, post the entire error message to your question. Do not just pick out a few words.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant! I have updated the parameters and the error is gone. However, when I now invoke I_NetLogonControl2, I get the return status as 5 which map to : ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. What permissions do I need? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the right number of parameters to [I_NetLogonControl2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Your definition is missing the QueryLevel parameter.

```
[DllImport("NetApi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint I_NetLogonControl2(
    [In] string ServerName,
    [In] DWORD FunctionCode,
    [In] DWORD QueryLevel,
    [In] byte[] InputData,
    out  IntPtr QueryInformation
 );
```

Also I_NetLogonControl2 does not set last error so that should not be included in the P/Invoke definition.

Comment: [Optional] doesn't mean what it does in the SAL annotations.  I just removed it.